# While using picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz6gT.png)   $ The data of assigned array is not showing in the pickerView. What mistake I am doing as I haven't being able to identify my mistake.
        Its .m file code:
    //  PickerViewController.m
    //  dropDownButtonTry
    //

```
#import "PickerViewController.h"

@interface PickerViewController ()
{
    NSArray *genderArray;
     NSArray *cityArray;
    NSArray *currentArray;
    UITextField *currentTextField;
}

@end

@implementation PickerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    cityArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Delhi",@"Mumbai",@"Chennai", nil];
    genderArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Male",@"Female",@"Transgender", nil];
    self.pickerView.hidden = YES;
    self.btnDoneOutlet.hidden = YES;



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

//Needed to prevent keyboard from opening
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    currentTextField = textField;
    if (textField == self.textFieldGenderOutlet) {
        currentArray = genderArray;
    }
    if (textField == self.textFieldCityOutlet) {
        currentArray = cityArray;
    }
    // do here everything you want
    NSLog(@"Pressed on TextField!");
    self.pickerView.hidden = NO;
    self.btnDoneOutlet.hidden = NO;

    [self.view endEditing:YES]; // Hide keyboard
    NSLog(@"****current array**** %@",currentArray);
    return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [currentArray count];

}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    [currentTextField setText:[currentArray objectAtIndex:row]];


}

-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [currentArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldGenderAction:(id)sender {
    self.pickerView.hidden = NO;
    self.btnDoneOutlet.hidden = NO;

}

- (IBAction)btnDone:(id)sender {
    self.pickerView.hidden = YES;
    self.btnDoneOutlet.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldCityAction:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: what is the issue occurs here ?

Comment: Sir issue is picker view not showing the array data. Please check in the question I have updated the simulator image.

Comment: you need to initialise in viewdidload and reload pickerview while refresh that array.

Comment: In textFieldShouldBeginEditing after self.pickerView.hidden = NO;, reload the picker components like [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload picker view :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    currentTextField = textField;
    if (textField == self.textFieldGenderOutlet) {
        currentArray = genderArray;
    }
    if (textField == self.textFieldCityOutlet) {
        currentArray = cityArray;
    }
    // do here everything you want
    NSLog(@"Pressed on TextField!");
    self.pickerView.hidden = NO;
    self.btnDoneOutlet.hidden = NO;

    [self.thePicker reloadAllComponents];


    [self.view endEditing:YES]; // Hide keyboard
    NSLog(@"****current array**** %@",currentArray);
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious help sir my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`currentArray` is assigned value in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` but it is not initialized anywhere in your code.

Just initialize `currentArray` in `viewDidLoad` like below:

```
currentArray = [NSArray new];
```

Comment: what is the use of allocation in here , just refresh your picker view thats all, the reason the item is not visible, in here currentArray is assign not store

Comment: I agree `pickerView` just needs to be refreshed. But we cannot assign array without initialising the same. `Array` will never reflect values if assigned without initialization.

Comment: who told like : assign  no need of initialising.